# How do I return Observable.create(true) from Guard when CanActivate

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have the following code...

```
@Injectable()
export class CanActivateIfWork implements CanActivate {
    constructor( public myService: MyService ) { }
    canActivate(
        route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
        state: RouterStateSnapshot,
    ) {
       return this.myService.shortPromise().map(message => {
          return true;
       });
    }
}
```

It works but now I need to call another service to replicate I change to

```
@Injectable()
export class CanActivateIfWork implements CanActivate {
    constructor( public myService: MyService ) { }
    canActivate(
        route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
        state: RouterStateSnapshot,
    ) {
       return this.myService.shortPromise().map(message => {
          return Observable.create(true);
       });
    }
}
```

This however doesn't seem to work. I tried this as well...

```
return this.myService.shortPromise().mergeMap(message => {
    return Observable.create(true);
});
```

How do I return this as an observable?

Comment: What does "now I need to call another service to replicate" mean? The last snippet should be `mergeMap(message => Observable.of(true))`, but it's not at all clear why you want/need to do that.

Comment: That is fine, it was only the other way so I could more easily set the breakpoint. The Observable.create(true) is taking the place of a service function that returns an Observable<boolean>

Comment: `TypeError: Observable_1.Observable.of is not a function
TypeError: Observable_1.Observable.of is not a function`

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/MGihChttJrTyvDjnu7DH?p=preview

Comment: `import "rxjs/add/observable/of"`

Comment: awesome thanks I will try it out in my project.